# Add and remove RealmChangeListener in View

Tags: java, android, realm, android-lifecycle

Is it a good idea to do this in a view that is going to be used in a `RecyclerView`?

```
@Override protected void onAttachedToWindow(){
    super.onAttachedToWindow();
    realmResult.addChangeListener(myChangeListener);
}

@Override protected void onDetachedFromWindow(){
    super.onDetachedFromWindow();
    realmResult.removeChangeListener(myChangeListener);
}
```

what if the view is used outside a `RecyclerView` and is not recycled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this [Activity methods:onCreate() and onDestroy()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9554885/activity-methodsoncreate-and-ondestroy)

`onDetachedFromWindow()` is called after `onDestroy()` which means you are calling methods on a RealmResults that could have been closed. So unless you add more safety checks it could crash.

Doing this would be safe though:

```
@Override protected void onDetachedFromWindow(){
    super.onDetachedFromWindow();
    if (realmResults.isValid()) {
      realmResult.removeChangeListener(myChangeListener);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Can i be sure that this will prevent memory leak?

Comment: Yes, you should be safe from memory leaks.